# How to solve - Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is a split function I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split2]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS
    (
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos

        UNION ALL

        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
        FROM Split
        WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT
        'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' =  SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos),1,CHARINDEX('$',SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos))-1),
        'UserId' =  SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos),CHARINDEX('$',SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos))+1,LEN(SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)))
    FROM Split
)
```

... and I tried to run this query:

```
Declare @String1 nvarchar(max);

SET @String1 = '1$1,0$1,2$2,1$2,0$2,3$3,1$3,0$3,4$4,3$4'

SELECT data, UserId 
FROM dbo.Split2(@String1, ',')
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

It's working perfectly, but I'm getting this error when I pass more than 4000 characters

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Then I tried to change

```
@String NVARCHAR(4000)
```

in split function to `nvarchar(max)`;

Then it shows

> the maximum allowed (4000).

How do I achieve this, any idea is highly appreciated. I wanna split string which may be more than 10000 or 20000 characters long.

Comment: The question is why would you want to split strings anyway? if it's to pass 'arrays' into and from stored procedures you better use table valued parameters. [Read this article](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters.html)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Actually, the question was started here sir, so i  Need to do something like this,by using that select query Im gonna store in a Temp Table and gonna use that table for calculation    http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/883585/Sql-Query-to-get-required-output?arn=0

Comment: Then I highly recommend changing that tree column to a table connected by a foreign key constraint to the main table. This will provide you a lot better performance and storage size since your tree members will be integer types (big int if you need it) and you wouldn't have to split any strings.

Comment: Yes its connected by foreign key ,Acutally the userid  is referenced by user_registration Table @ZoharPeled

Comment: Yes, but the tree column itself should be in a separated table. Keeping delimited strings in a database is almost always the wrong way to go. In 16 years of programming I've only had to do it once, and even that was just to because the code using the data needed comma delimited values. I've never encountered any situation that requires a delimited string to be manipulated in sql that transforming to a table that would not improve both code readability and performance.

Comment: Actually, that is the Tree of that customer, then How can i maintain the tree in Table?can you show  me the sample structure?

Comment: Thanks for you kind attention on my question . very much

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by 'Tree of that customer', but if you can store it in your database as a comma-delimited value, then surly you can also store it as rows of a table. If the order of the numbers in that string is meaningful, you will need to add and maintain an ordinal column.

Comment: I meant the tree is  customer Introducer,Introducer of Introducer and so on , Its a MLM Application, If i maintain that in ordinal column then table row would be very long , so does it cause any performance while run select query ?

Comment: So it describes recursive data. For recursive data you don't need an ordinal column, but a Introducer  column. so if your string looks like `1,2,3,4` and it means that 1 is the Introducer of 2, and 2 is the Introducer of 3, and 3 is the Introducer of 4, your table will have these values: {1,null}, {2,1}, {3,2} and {4,3}. this way you can tell that 1 has 
no Introducer, and 3 is the Introducer of 4 and so on. Anyway it's only a recommendation, you don't really have to do what I say, you know :-)

Comment: yes , you are  right sir, good to talk to you sir. Thank you for your timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@String` parameter type to `NVARCHAR(max)` and add explicit cast to `bigint` of the 0 in the first `SELECT`, because [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186323.aspx) returns

> **bigint** if expressionToSearch is of the varchar(max), nvarchar(max), or
>   varbinary(max) data types; otherwise, **int**.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split2]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(max),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS
    (
        SELECT CAST(0 AS bigint) AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos

        UNION ALL

        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
        FROM Split
        WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT
        'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' =  SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos),1,CHARINDEX('$',SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos))-1),
        'UserId' =  SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos),CHARINDEX('$',SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos))+1,LEN(SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)))
    FROM Split
)
```

Comment: Thanks sir, But the string have 30k Characters ,and this may vary in next time, its not fixed value, Can i Post the string Value?

Comment: The function in my answer should work fine with such string. Please try and let me know if you get any error message.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server strings are limited to 4000 Unicode characters e.g. NVARCHAR(MAX). This is the reason for your error.

You can change it to non-Unicode and you'll get 8000 e.g. VARCHAR(MAX).

Getting more than this would require you somehow controlling how big a string is created when your code runs. I'm not completely clear how it is working so I am not able to modify it further.

Comment: Sir, The string may be 30k characters,

Comment: That's why you need not let the string get that big. You effectively need to split the string before it gets to the function.

Comment: @SimonDarlow, with `nvarchar(max)` [max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)